# BeforeSave not being called during seeding

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Is `beforeSave()` supposed to be called during seeding?

The `beforeSave()` method in my model table currently gets called when I go through the app (in both edit and add), as intended fields get updated after the form submission.

However, when I seed the database after truncating the table, these same fields remain at their default value.

Seed:

```
public function run()
{
    $data = [
            ['season_id'=>1, 'league_id'=>1, 'game_date'=>'2017-01-01', 'game_type_id'=>2, 'user_pt'=>1, 'opponent'=>'Vancouver', 'opponent_pt'=>2, 'is_decision'=>1, 'mins'=>60, 'ga'=>2, 'sog'=>24],
            ['season_id'=>1, 'league_id'=>1, 'game_date'=>'2017-01-02', 'game_type_id'=>2, 'user_pt'=>2, 'opponent'=>'Vancouver', 'opponent_pt'=>1, 'is_decision'=>1, 'mins'=>59, 'secs'=>45, 'ga'=>1, 'sog'=>27],
            ['season_id'=>1, 'league_id'=>1, 'game_date'=>'2017-01-03', 'game_type_id'=>2, 'user_pt'=>4, 'opponent'=>'Vancouver', 'opponent_pt'=>1, 'is_decision'=>1, 'mins'=>60, 'ga'=>1, 'sog'=>19],
            ['season_id'=>1, 'league_id'=>1, 'game_date'=>'2017-01-04', 'game_type_id'=>2, 'user_pt'=>5, 'opponent'=>'Edmonton', 'opponent_pt'=>2, 'is_decision'=>1, 'mins'=>58, 'secs'=>24, 'ga'=>1, 'sog'=>19],
            ['season_id'=>1, 'league_id'=>1, 'game_date'=>'2017-01-05', 'game_type_id'=>2, 'user_pt'=>3, 'opponent'=>'Calgary', 'opponent_pt'=>4, 'is_decision'=>1, 'mins'=>59, 'secs'=>10, 'ga'=>1, 'sog'=>19],
    ];

    $table = $this->table('games');
    $table->insert($data)->save();
}
```

BeforeSave

```
// In a table or behavior class
public function beforeSave($event, $entity, $options)
{
    // calculate record if part of decision
    if (isset($entity->is_decision) && $entity->is_decision == 1){
        //reset
        $entity->l = 0;
        $entity->w = 0;
        $entity->t = 0;
        $entity->otl = 0;
        $entity->is_shutout = 0;


        //calculate result of game
        if($entity->is_overtime == 0){
            //loss
            if($entity->opponent_pt > $entity->user_pt)
                $entity->l = 1;
            elseif($entity->opponent_pt < $entity->user_pt)
                $entity->w = 1;
            //tie
            elseif($entity->opponent_pt = $entity->user_pt)
                $entity->t = 1;
        }
        else{
            //ot loss
            if($entity->opponent_pt > $entity->user_pt)
                $entity->otl = 1;
        }

        //calculate shutout
        if($entity->opponent_pt == 0)
            $entity->is_shutout = 1;

        $entity->abs_game_time = 0;
        //calculate absolute game time
        if(isset($entity->mins) && is_numeric($entity->mins) && $entity->mins > 0)
        {

            if(isset($entity->secs) && is_numeric($entity->secs) && $entity->secs > 0){
                 $entity->abs_game_time = ($entity->mins * 60 + $entity->secs)/60;
            }
            else 
                $entity->abs_game_time = $entity->mins;
        }
    }
}
```

Edit #1

Updated code snippets, still no  go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't work because seeds don't use the Cake ORM.

```
use Phinx\Db\Table as BaseTable;
class Table extends BaseTable { /*...*/ }
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming my suspicion.